# Is there a way in Install4j to expose additional logging output during counter signing?

Tags: code-signing, install4j, timestamping, digicert

I'm encountering a counter signing error while building an installer

> Creating media file 'Multi-File Windows':
>    Collecting files:
>    Compiling launchers:
>    Creating media file:
>      Signing executable
>   install4j: compilation failed. Reason: error during counter signing

I'm wondering if there is a way to expose more information on why the counter signing failed.

I tried two different DigiCert Time Stamping services; Verisign and Globalsign. Both returned the same error, so I'm thinking it isn't an issue on their end. But I don't have enough information to figure out what could be going wrong.

This was on Install4j version 5.1.15

Answer (score 0):

You can see the full chains of exceptions if you enable verbose output on the "Build" step.